# What is this date format: YYYYMMDDTHHMISS

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula

Can some please explain the meaning of this date format: YYYYMMDDTHHMISS
I have a feed containing a date and need to validate the date format is: YYYYMMDDTHHMISS

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jeeped is right.

[Is the ISO format](https://github.com/fmidev/smartmet-plugin-timeseries/wiki/SmartMet-plugin-TimeSeries) of a an extended Date + Time setup.

It's composed of: `Year[YYYY] + Month[MM] + Day[DD] + Timeseperator between date and time [T] + Hour[HH] + Minute[MI] + Seconds[SS]`